# jsf2 f:ajax render issue in datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have a datatable and for each line have a delete linkcommand, as following:

```
<h:dataTable value='#{glbProjectDtoList}' var='projectDto'
    binding='#{projectController.projectDataTable}' styleClass='display'
    id='tblProject' rowClasses='gradeA, gradeA'
    columnClasses='projectTableName, projectTableProgress, projectTableAction'>
    ......
    <h:commandLink
        action="#{projectController.delete(projectDto.projectId)}">
        <img class="btnDeleteProject mr5"
            src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/icons/dark/trash.png" />
        <f:ajax execute="@form"
            onevent="function(data) {deleteProjectEventHandler(data);}"
            render=":tblProject" />
    </h:commandLink>
    ......
</h:dataTable>
```

The delete function works fine, but the whole datatable is not reRendered, is it because the action nested in data table or by some other reason?

---

Update :

It's not working, after remove (:), throw following exception:

```
    javax.faces.FacesException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'tblProject' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt68
```

means without (:), the element must be in same h:form tag.

---

Thanks in advance.

-Cow

Comment: try `render="tblProject"` or `render="@form"` instead of `render=":tblProject"`

Comment: render="tblProject" throw exception with unknown id 'tblProject', render="@form" doesn't make sense since datatable not in form.

Comment: what is the full id of the table (view source in your browser)?

Comment: Your table wrapped eventually in some `h:form` , right ?

Comment: it's not, i have following structure.<h:form>.button.</h:form><h:datatable><h:form>button</h:form><h:form>button</h:form>...</h:datatable>, and the button in first h:form can render datatable with render=":tblProject", but the button within datatable can't. :(

Comment: try to take out the `h:form` from withing the table and wrap the table with one `h:form`...

Comment: it's not working, after I wrapped datatable with form, only last action button fired action, means if I want to delete any row, always the last one deleted. and the render='tblProject' still not working.

Comment: Given your strange problems with `<f:ajax>` in the current and the previous questions, I think that your JSF project setup is seriously messed up. Perhaps you've duplicate different versioned JSF libraries/implementations in the runtime classpath or something. Or you've messed too much with project's classpath/buildpath while you're supposed to keep off from it. I recommend to start a clean project based on a sane book/tutorial wherein you make absolutely sure that you *understand* every single step of configuring the project and writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `:` in front of the id:

`<f:ajax execute="@form" onevent="function(data) {deleteProjectEventHandler(data);}" render="tblProject"/>`

If the id starts with a separator character (usually `:`) the component is searched from the root component, otherwise it is searched from the next `NamingContainer`.

Have a look at the javadoc for more information: [UIComponent.findComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly happening because the id of the datatable is not found in the viewroot when component state is getting refreshed.

> To find out the exact ID by which this component is present on the
>   viewroot, please check the page source and find out the ID by which
>   this datatable is rendered.

You need to use the same ID as those found in the viewSource to allow the component to be visible in viewRoot when the state is changed.

Alternatively, UIComponent.findComponent will also help and if ID you are specifying is correct it will return you the UIComponent instance else it will return null.

Comment: the ID is exactly 'tblProject', but it said can't find.

Answer (score 0):

I have go another approach, use hiding form outside of the table. It works.

Thanks everyone ;)