# <h:dataTable> not updating/refreshing after <f:ajax> has been performed

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I am having some issues with my `<h:dataTable>` where I cannot get it to update/refresh upon submitting an `<f:ajax>` request which, resides within this table component. The `<f:ajax>` listener attribute triggers a specific row to be removed from the `<h:dataTable>`. Could someone please assist me in getting this to work.

Code fragment from my JSF page:

```
<h:dataTable id="table1">
    <h:column>
       <f:facet name="header">Object Name:</f:facet>
       <h:outputText value="#{object.name}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
       <f:facet name="header">Action:</f:facet>
       <h:form>
          <h:commandButton value="Delete">
             <f:ajax listener="#{objectBean.delete(object.id)}" render=":table1"/>
          </h:commandButton>
       </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I have also tried to wrap this `<h:dataTable>` component within a `<h:panelGroup>` component and it still did not work unfortunately. Any tips on getting this to work?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797269/jsf2-fajax-render-issue-in-datatable

Comment: Yes, although still does not help. Render attribute is correctly referenced, however not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to : [Datatable not rendering with ajax call in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213031/datatable-not-rendering-with-ajax-call-in-jsf)

Move your  to wrap the whole datatable, check your network traffic in chrome F12 to see what the sent/returned response is and see if its giving you back the right table to update.